# Paypal sandbox not working anymore

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Everything was working fine last Friday, but today I have been getting the following message:

[image: Click to see full resolution].

The message I get when trying to make a payment using paypal sandbox is this:

> We can't process your payment right now, so please try again later.
>   We're sorry for the inconvenience.

It's been like this all day, not sure if something has happened to my system or if something has happened to paypal's sandbox?

Comment: I'm getting this error as well (both yesterday and this morning), no indication why. I've contacted support, but no answer as of yet.

Comment: @MarkBell, Thanks very much for the comment!  Please do post back here if you get a reply from paypal-support.

Comment: @MarkBell, do you have a link, so I can contact paypal support too?

Comment: The only link I have is https://ppmts.custhelp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTIFICATION FROM PAYPAL:**

> Notification: Issues with Sandbox with preconfigured accounts - Jan 24

Source: https://www.x.com/content/notification-issues-sandbox-preconfigured-accounts-jan-24

**WORKAROUND:**

Create a non UK preconfigured account or create a manual account.

Answer (score 0):

If everything worked fine then maybe time messed it up so wait for time or check it out again later :). If too long then contact paypal support.

Comment: Do you have a link, so I can contact paypal support?